# An error(object variable or with block variable not set) prompts when I call macro

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I use uerform with button, and TextBox1,2,3.
according value in TextBox1 (ISBN code) I would like to find title and author and put values to TextBox2 and TextBox3.
but it gives me a error message object variable or with block variable not set and highliht the lines:
TextBox3.Value = oTitle.Text
TextBox2.Text = oAuthor.Text
Thank you for your help

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
 Dim SourceWindow As Window
 Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument60
 Dim xWords As IXMLDOMNode
 Dim xType As IXMLDOMNode
 Dim xword As IXMLDOMNodeList
 Dim xWordChild As IXMLDOMNode
 Dim oAttributes As IXMLDOMNamedNodeMap
 Dim oTitle As IXMLDOMNode
 Dim oAuthor As IXMLDOMNode
 Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument60
 Set xWords = New DOMDocument60
 xmlDoc.async = False
 xmlDoc.validateOnParse = False

 r = CStr(TextBox1.Value) 'CStr(ActiveCell.Value)
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 xmlDoc.Load ("http://xisbn.worldcat.org/webservices/xid/isbn/" _
              + r + "?method=getMetadata&format=xml&fl=author,title")

 Set xWords = xmlDoc

     For Each xType In xWords.ChildNodes
         Set xword = xType.ChildNodes
         For Each xWordChild In xword
             Set oAttributes = xWordChild.Attributes
             On Error Resume Next
             Set oTitle = oAttributes.getNamedItem("title")
             Set oAuthor = oAttributes.getNamedItem("author")
             On Error GoTo 0
         Next xWordChild
     Next xType

  TextBox3.Value = oTitle.Text
  TextBox2.Text = oAuthor.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Text` is read only use `.Value`

Comment: Hello, thank you for quick response, it helps. many thanks.